# Column Operations in file Linux Shell

Tags: linux, bash, awk

I have a file with entries seperated by an empty space. For example:

**example.txt**

```
24676 256 218503341 2173
13236272 500 1023073758 5089
2230304 96 15622969 705
0 22 0 526
13277 28 379182 141
```

I would like to print, in the command line, the outcome of "column 1/ column 3" or simila. I believe it can be done with awk. However, some entries are 0, hence division by 0 gives:

> fatal: division by zero attempted

In a more advanced case, I would like to find the median value (or some percentile) of the division.

Comment: Okay. So what should it do if it's dividing by zero?

Comment: What do you want to do when the 3rd column is 0?  Ignore the line?  Hard-code some constant value?

Comment: I guess hard-code the value 0. Because it will need to be counted as zero in the percentile calculation.

Comment: For example, row 1: 24676/218503341=0.0001, row 2: 0.0129, row 3: 0.14, row 4: 0, row 5: 0.035. Then find the median of these numbers (0.0129).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many ways to ignore the row with a zero divisor, including:

```
awk '$3 != 0 { print $1/$3 }' your-data-file

awk '{ if ($3 != 0) print $1/$3 }' your-data-file
```

The question changed — to print 0 instead.  The answer is not much harder:

```
awk '{ if ($3 != 0) print $1/$3; else print 0 }' your-data-file
```

Medians and other percentiles are much fiddlier to deal with.  It's easiest if the data is in sorted order.  So much easier that I'd expect to use a numeric sort and then process the data from there.

---

I dug out an old shell script which computes descriptive statistics - min, max, mode, median, and deciles of a single numeric column of data:

```
:   "@(#)$Id: dstats.sh,v 1.2 1997/06/02 21:45:00 johnl Exp $"
#
#   Calculate Descriptive Statistics: min, max, median, mode, deciles

sort -n $* |
awk 'BEGIN { max = -999999999; min = 999999999; }
    {   # Accumulate basic data
        count[$1]++;
        item[++n] = $1;
        if ($1 > max) max = $1;
        if ($1 < min) min = $1;
    }
END {   # Print Descriptive Statistics
        printf("# Count = %d\n", n);
        printf("# Min = %d\n", min);
        decile = 1;
        for (decile = 10; decile < 100; decile += 10)
        {
            idx = int((decile * n) / 100) + 1;
            printf("# %d%% decile = %d\n", decile, item[idx]);
            if (decile == 50)
                median = item[idx];
        }
        printf("# Max = %d\n", max);

        printf("# Median = %d\n", median);
        for (i in count)
        {
            if (count[i] > count[mode])
                mode = i;
        }
        printf("# Mode = %d\n", mode);
    }'
```

The initial values of `min` and `max` are not exactly scientific.  It serves to illustrate a point.

(This 1997 version is almost identical to its 1991 predecessor - all except for the version information line is identical, in fact.  So, the code is over 20 years old.)

Comment: I actually want the percentile of the output. So if I pipe it to sort -g, I need to select the 0.5*$NR

Comment: You'll need to define what you mean by 'the percentile of the output'.  Do you mean the row nearest the Nth percentile, or the all the rows up to the Nth percentile, or ...  What are the other constraints on what can be done?  For example, can we run the output of the division through the `sort` program and then process the result with a second `awk` script?

Comment: -Yes we can run the output of the dvision through the sort program and then process the result with a second awk script.

Comment: By median, I define the middle value. In general, x% percentile is the value below the x% of the output. What I need exactly is any percentile from the division of column 1 and 3.

Answer (score 2):

Here's one solution:

```
awk '
  $3 != 0 { vals[$NR]=$1/$3; sum += vals[$NR]; print vals[$NR] }
  $3 == 0 { vals[$NR]=0; print "skipping division by 0" }
  END { sort vals; print "Mean = " sum/$NR ", Median ~ " vals[$NR/2] }
  ' < your_file
```

This will calculate, print, and accumulate the quotients if the 3<sup>rd</sup> column is not zero.  When it reaches the end of your file (which should *not* have an empty line), it will print the mean and median of all the quotients, assuming 0 for each line in which it would have divided by zero.

In `awk`, `$n` means the `n`<sup>th</sup> field, starting with 1, and `$NR` means the number of records (that is, the number of lines) that have been processed. Each quotient is stored in the array `vals`, enabling us to calculate the median value.

In real life, the median is defined as the "middle" item given an odd number of elements, or the mean of the two "middle" items given an even number of elements.

And you're on your own when it comes to implementing the `sort` function!

Comment: That's the mean rather than the median, isn't it?

Comment: Yes.  I _hate_ arrays in `awk`.  :-)  Why do you and I seem to answer so many of the same questions?

Comment: I guess it means we have sufficiently similar backgrounds that we can both answer similar questions.  Arrays in `awk` are useful for many purposes, but sorting is ... not a built-in in POSIX `awk` (but is available in GNU `awk`).  Of course, Jon Bentley wrote a complete library of sort functions in `awk` along with test scaffolding in one of his Programming Pearls books, so it can be done if necessary.